# Improving a script to compare the number of files between two folders visually

Tags: bash, macos, shell, terminal, scripting

I'm very new to writing scripts.

I have a MacOS script that compares the number of files in two different folders of the same name per my workflow. It reads folders at a specific level for RAW photos and a different set for processed photos. The script works perfectly, but I'd love to make it visually easier to parse through and find any discrepancies. An example of the output is as follows:

[Example output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bTsLD.png)

Which is a pain in the ass to parse through the larger jobs when the folder count grows.

Source code of the script is here:

```
echo "Capture Folder:"
read folder1
echo "Output Folder:"
read folder2

echo "******** Capture Folder Contains the following files ********"
find "$folder1" -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1  -type d -print0 | sort -z | while read$
    files=$(find "$dir" -name "[!.]*" -maxdepth 1 -type f | wc -l)
    printf  "%5d files in %s\n" "$files" "$dir"
done

echo "******** Output Folder Contains the following files ********"
find "$folder2" -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1  -type d -print0 | sort -z | while read$
    files=$(find "$dir" -name "[!.]*" -maxdepth 1 -type f | wc -l)
    printf "%5d files in %s\n" "$files" "$dir"
done
```

Any ideas how to add something visually to the end of a line to denote that it has a matching partner in the Output folder?

Comment: You could look into `comm` to find files that exist in only one of the directories, or in both of them.

Comment: @BenjaminW. Unless ```comm``` is extension agnostic, can't do that, because they're different file types in each location. Typically the 'Capture' folder contains RAW (.CR2, .NEF, .IIQ) images, and output is typcally JPEG or TIFF.

Comment: You'd have to massage the inputs, with something like `find -printf` – but without example input and your expected output, it's hard to be specific.